# Is there any way to find next similar tag without querying all tags at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html-parsing

I'm trying to implement my own link hinting script for surf browser, and
I've been bumping into noticeable performance issues on pages with a
huge number of links. For example, it takes about 2 seconds to hint all
visible links on https://gunther.suckless.org/patches/ and 3 seconds on
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan. I think, the problem is that I'm
trying to find all the link tags using `querySelectorAll("a")` (or
`getElementsByTagName("a")` - it has almost the same performance in my
case) and then filtering all these tags through the function that checks
whether a link is in the viewport or not (in other words, a link finding
procedure wastes most of the time on links that won't be displayed
anyway):

```
var all_elems = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < all_elems.length; i++) {
  if (isHintDisplay(all_elems[i])) {
    hint_elems.push(all_elems[i]);
  }
}
```

I'd thought that, probably, a "manual" link tags iterations, that process one link tag at a time and stop when invisible links would found, would be a more optimal solution.
I've tried to implement these iterations using `querySelector("a")` / `parentElement` / `nextElementSibling`, but ended up with ugly and absolutely non-robust code...

Is there any other way to find previous/next similar tags without using
`querySelectorAll` / `getElementsByTagName`? Or these performance issues is inherent to Javascript itself and there is not much can be done to
improve situation?

P.S. It is assumed that processed tags won't contain any IDs and classes.

**ADDED**

Implementation of isHintDisplay:

```
function isHintDisplay(elem) {
  var pos = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                            window.innerHeight);
  return !(pos.bottom < 0 || pos.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious.  My first thought would be to comment out the call to isHintDisplay, and see if the performance issues aleviate.  Essentially, identifying further where the performance issue is originating from.

Comment: I say that as I'm not sure that there is a selector that exists that would find only elements in the viewport.  Because if there was, that would be *magical* (meaning I would love it)

Comment: I added to main post implementation of `isHintDisplay` function, and it uses fairly standard solution with `getBoundingClientRect()`. I could try to comment out this function but I think there is no point in it because this function is essential for this script, and I have no idea how it can be reimplemented...